# How do I get the minimal price of a grouped product from a product collection?

Tags: catalog, collection

I'm loading all products using the product collection resource model.

```
$_categoryId = $this->getCategoryId();

$_productCollection = Mage::getResourceModel('catalog/product_collection')
        ->addMinimalPrice()
        ->addFinalPrice()
        ->addTaxPercents()
        ->addCategoryFilter(Mage::getModel('catalog/category')->load($_categoryId))
        ->addAttributeToSelect('*')
        ->addAttributeToFilter('status', 1)
        ->addAttributeToFilter('visibility', 4);
```

I'm however not able to display the minimal price of grouped products using for example.

```
echo $_productCollection->getFirstItem()->getMinimalPrice();
```

This does work for simple products. This seems to be related to the fact that this is a core/template block type and not a catalog/product_list block. But using catalog/product_list is not an option due to other reasons.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

If you update your code so it does no just select * but instead use the catalog config attributes then your code works for all product types.

```
Mage::getSingleton('catalog/config')->getProductAttributes()
```

Your code should look like.

```
$_categoryId = $this->getCategoryId();

$_productCollection = Mage::getResourceModel('catalog/product_collection')
    ->addMinimalPrice()
    ->addFinalPrice()
    ->addTaxPercents()
    ->addCategoryFilter(Mage::getModel('catalog/category')->load($_categoryId))
    ->addAttributeToSelect(Mage::getSingleton('catalog/config')->getProductAttributes())
    ->addAttributeToFilter('status', 1)
    ->addAttributeToFilter('visibility', 4);
```

In this case the correct minimal prices will be loaded for each type of product.

Comment: Took a while to come back to this.. but that did it. Thank you!